# django-tellme rendering problem in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I installed [this](https://github.com/ludrao/django-tellme) app but when I run it, I get a error in django admin, it does not rendering HTMl text as it should have done, I'm not familiar with how to make these customizations, I have also posted a [issue](https://github.com/ludrao/django-tellme/issues/36), if it help in understanding my problem, I hope I get a solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check and asked this question to few more peoples and check the repo carefully and I got the solution that if I use

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
```

when returning elements then it will render html in admin too

you can see it [here](https://github.com/ludrao/django-tellme/pull/34/commits/af57b3fd8736231ea3ce7ac63852244c4cfddf06)